# Query DB:raw in laravel

Tags: laravel

How do I add a where clause on my `DB:raw` query? I want to query those users whose profile status is Public. This is my query:

```
$results = DB::select(DB::raw('SELECT *, ( 6371 * acos( cos( radians(' . $lat . ') ) * cos( radians( lat ) ) * cos( radians( lng ) - radians(' . $lng . ') ) + sin( radians(' . $lat .') ) * sin( radians(lat) ) ) ) AS distance FROM users HAVING distance < ' . $distance . ' ORDER BY distance'));
```

Comment: Maybe read a tutorial on basic MySQL if you’re not sure where to put a `WHERE` clause in a statement?

Comment: I just read some tutorial sir but the query is given by Google I don't know how to add a where clause

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could place it before or after the `ORDER BY` as below:

```
$results = DB::select(
    DB::raw('
        SELECT
            *, ( 6371 * acos( cos( radians(' . $lat . ') ) * cos( radians( lat ) ) * cos( radians( lng ) - radians(' . $lng . ') ) + sin( radians(' . $lat .') ) * sin( radians(lat) ) ) ) AS distance 
        FROM 
            users 
        WHERE
            status = "public"
            AND
            distance < "'. $distance .'"
        ORDER BY 
            distance
    ')
);
```

Seriously, though, this is an incredibly simple thing to do in SQL and you should take 30 minutes out to go over a basic tutorial before going ahead with what it is you're working on.

**General**

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/a-basic-mysql-tutorial

**WHERE clause specific**

http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-where/

Comment: sir i get an error ..syntax error, unexpected 'public' (T_PUBLIC)

Comment: I've just edited the code. Please try the new version. I put double quotes around "public" and also changed your `HAVING` to be part of the `WHERE` clause since you do not have a `GROUP BY`

Comment: Sorry, just updated it again. You need double quotes on the distance variable too.

Comment: thank you sir...how can i add a where not in clause here sir? i would like to add a where not in clause so that the query itself cannot return a value on a login user..i would store a session value on the where not in clause

Comment: You can add `AND username NOT IN ('user1','user2','user3')` etc